# Mysql getting json from nested queries

Tags: php, mysql, json

I had two tables whch are visitormaster and visitor comment.
Visitor master has unique visitorid and comment bt that visitor stores in visitorcomment using visitorid as foreign key there.
I want to get data in following format:

```
[
    {
        "visitorid":1,
        "visitorname":"ABC",
        "comment":
                {
                    "commentid":2;
                    "comment":"XYZ"
                }
    }
    {
        "visitorid":2,
        "visitorname":"LMN",
        "comment":
                {
                    "commentid":4;
                    "comment":"MNO"
                }
    }

]

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitormaster");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{
    $result = array();
    while($rlt = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $result[] = $rlt[];
        $vid=$rlt["visitorid"];
        $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitorcomment WHERE visitor_id = "."'$vid'");
        while($rltcomment = mysql_fetch_array($sql1,MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            $commentresult[] = $rltcomment[];
        }
        $newresult=array($result,"comment"=>$rltcomment[0]);
    }
    $array=array("result_data"=>$newresult);
    $this->response($this->json($array), 200);
}
```

But there is no output.

Answer (score 0):

quote missing in SQL statement mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitormaster);

to see errors use ini_set("Display_errors","On"); to turn error reporting on. this will give errors.

Answer (score 0):

double quote is missing in `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitormaster);` and Semi comma is also missing in `$newresult = array($result, "comment" => $rltcomment[0])`